# Select country has the highest account balance

Tags: mysql, window-functions

I am new to SQL.I have two tables Customers and deposit_transactions. I am trying to s`elect the country which has the highest account balance for each date`. I am joining deposit_transactions table(to get the sum of amount based on customer_id) and joining with customers table to get the Country

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE deposit_transactions (
  `deposit_id` VARCHAR(7),
  `customer_id` VARCHAR(5),
  `date` TEXT,
  `transaction_type` VARCHAR(7),
  `amount` INTEGER,
  `currency` VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO deposit_transactions
  (`deposit_id`, `customer_id`, `date`, `transaction_type`, `amount`, `currency`)
VALUES
  ('DE47653', 'DO900', '1/1/2019', 'pay_in', '10000', 'EUR'),
  ('DE47654', 'DO901', '2/1/2019', 'pay_in', '10000', 'EUR'),
  ('DE47655', 'DO902', '2/1/2019', 'pay_in', '10000', 'EUR'),
  ('UK47656', 'DO903', '3/1/2019', 'pay_in', '10000', 'GBP'),
  ('UK47657', 'DO904', '3/1/2019', 'pay_in', '130000', 'GBP'),
  ('DE47658', 'DO905', '3/1/2019', 'pay_in', '140000', 'EUR'),
  ('DE47659', 'DO906', '3/1/2019', 'pay_in', '10000', 'EUR'),
  ('DE47660', 'DO907', '3/1/2019', 'pay_in', '10000', 'EUR'),
  ('DE47661', 'DO908', '3/1/2019', 'pay_in', '100000', 'EUR'),
  ('DE47662', 'DO909', '4/1/2019', 'pay_in', '10000', 'EUR'),
  ('UK47663', 'DO910', '4/1/2019', 'pay_in', '10000', 'GBP'),
  ('UK47664', 'DO911', '4/1/2019', 'pay_in', '5000', 'GBP'),
  ('UK47665', 'DO912', '4/1/2019', 'pay_in', '4000', 'GBP'),
  ('DE47666', 'DO913', '5/1/2019', 'pay_in', '10000', 'EUR'),
  ('DE47661', 'DO908', '5/1/2019', 'pay_out', '50000', 'EUR'),
  ('DE47667', 'DO914', '11/1/2019', 'pay_in', '30000', 'EUR'),
  ('DE47668', 'DO915', '11/1/2019', 'pay_in', '10000', 'EUR'),
  ('DE47669', 'DO916', '11/1/2019', 'pay_in', '25000', 'EUR'),
  ('DE47670', 'DO917', '11/1/2019', 'pay_in', '50000', 'EUR'),
  ('DE47667', 'DO914', '12/1/2019', 'pay_out', '7000', 'EUR'),
  ('DE47667', 'DO914', '12/15/2019', 'pay_in', '12000', 'EUR'),
  ('DE47671', 'DO918', '1/1/2021', 'pay_in', '9000', 'EUR'),
  ('DE47672', 'DO919', '1/1/2021', 'pay_in', '10000', 'EUR'),
  ('DE47673', 'DO920', '1/1/2021', 'pay_in', '11000', 'EUR'),
  ('DE47674', 'DO921', '1/1/2021', 'pay_in', '12000', 'EUR'),
  ('DE47675', 'DO922', '1/1/2021', 'pay_in', '13000', 'EUR'),
  ('DE47676', 'DO923', '1/1/2021', 'pay_in', '14000', 'EUR'),
  ('DE47677', 'DO924', '1/1/2021', 'pay_in', '30000', 'EUR'),
  ('DE47678', 'DO925', '1/1/2021', 'pay_in', '16000', 'EUR');

CREATE TABLE customers (
  `customer_id` VARCHAR(5),
  `country` VARCHAR(7)
);

INSERT INTO customers
  (`customer_id`, `country`)
VALUES
  ('DO900', 'Germany'),
  ('DO901', 'Germany'),
  ('DO902', 'Spain'),
  ('DO903', 'UK'),
  ('DO904', 'UK'),
  ('DO905', 'Austria'),
  ('DO906', 'Germany'),
  ('DO907', 'Germany'),
  ('DO908', 'Germany'),
  ('DO909', 'Germany'),
  ('DO910', 'UK'),
  ('DO911', 'UK'),
  ('DO912', 'UK'),
  ('DO913', 'Germany'),
  ('DO914', 'Austria'),
  ('DO915', 'Germany'),
  ('DO916', 'Austria'),
  ('DO917', 'Germany'),
  ('DO918', 'Germany'),
  ('DO919', 'Spain'),
  ('DO920', 'Germany'),
  ('DO921', 'Spain'),
  ('DO922', 'Germany'),
  ('DO923', 'Germany'),
  ('DO924', 'Germany'),
  ('DO925', 'Spain'),
  ('DO926', 'Germany'),
  ('DO927', 'Germany'),
  ('DO928', 'Germany'),
  ('DO929', 'Germany'),
  ('DO711', 'UK'),
  ('DO712', 'UK'),
  ('DO713', 'Germany'),
  ('DO714', 'Austria'),
  ('DO715', 'Germany'),
  ('DO716', 'Austria'),
  ('DO717', 'Germany'),
  ('DO718', 'Germany'),
  ('DO719', 'Spain'),
  ('DO720', 'Germany'),
  ('DO721', 'Spain'),
  ('DO722', 'Germany'),
  ('DO723', 'Germany'),
  ('DO724', 'Germany'),
  ('DO725', 'Spain'),
  ('DO726', 'Germany'),
  ('DO727', 'Germany'),
  ('DO728', 'Germany'),
  ('DO729', 'Germany');
```

---

Below is the sample query I created. But I am not sure if its correct

**Query**

```
SELECT t.customer_id,
       c.country,t.total_amount
FROM  (SELECT customer_id,
              date,
              transaction_type,
              Sum(amount)
                OVER (
                  partition BY customer_id ) AS total_amount_transfered,
              Row_number()
                OVER (
                  partition BY customer_id
                  ORDER BY date DESC)        AS n
       FROM   deposit_transactions)t
      INNER JOIN customers AS c
              ON c.customer_id = t.customer_id
WHERE  t.n = 1
       AND t.transaction_type = 'pay_in' order by total_amount desc limit 1;
```

---

Comment: `total_amount` should be `total_amount_transfered`

Comment: You don't need both `t.n = 1` and `ORDER BY total_amount DESC LIMIT 1`. Both of them are selecting the first row.

Comment: @Barmar I have updated my requirement.Apologies from my side as the context was not clear

Comment: How do you handle different currencies? Also shouldn't you subtract the pay_out transactions? @Prady_decon

Comment: Yes those two has to be considered.But I am  not sure as I am facing challenge in implementing the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**. Finding the total balance amount for each country.

Since you need to get the balance and you have two kinds of transactions, I'd rather transform the "*pay-out*" transactions into negative balance and leave "*pay-in*" transactions as are. Also you should take into account the different currencies, because "*GBP*" currency has a higher value than "*EUR*" currency (GBP ~ EUR*0.85). If you don't want to consider "*pay-out*" negative impact, you can transform them to 0. This balance wrangling is done here by a [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) statement.

Then the balances are aggregated with a `SUM` function over the corresponding countries (accessible because of the `JOIN` operation) and grouped over the "*country*" and "*date*" field.

```
SELECT country,
       date AS transaction_date,
--     STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y') AS transaction_date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'pay_in' AND currency = 'EUR' THEN amount 
                WHEN transaction_type = 'pay_in' AND currency = 'GBP' THEN amount/0.85
--              WHEN transaction_type = 'pay_out'                      THEN 0
                WHEN transaction_type = 'pay_out' AND currency = 'EUR' THEN -amount
                WHEN transaction_type = 'pay_out' AND currency = 'GBP' THEN -amount/0.85 
           END) AS amount_eur
FROM       deposit_transactions dt
INNER JOIN customers c
        ON dt.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY country,
         transaction_date
```

Optionally in this step, you could also transform the "*date*" field from the `TEXT` type to the `DATE` type using the `STR_TO_DATE` function.

---

**Step 2**. Ranking the countries over the summed amounts.

In order to apply a rank, you use the [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) window function, to partition on the transaction date and order by the balance amount descendently.

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
              PARTITION BY transaction_date
              ORDER     BY amount_eur DESC ) AS rn
FROM   total_amounts_per_country
```

---

**Step 3**. Selecting the country having the highest balance.

You can just all rows which have the rank equal to 1, given that there will be a 1 for each date. Then select the interesting fields, namely "*transaction_date*" and "*country*".

```
SELECT transaction_date, 
       country
FROM ranked_countries
WHERE rn = 1
```

---

**Full Query**. It uses MySQL [common table expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) to combine the three steps.

```
WITH total_amounts_per_country AS(
    SELECT country,
           date AS transaction_date,
--         STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y') AS transaction_date,
           SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'pay_in' AND currency = 'EUR' THEN amount 
                    WHEN transaction_type = 'pay_in' AND currency = 'GBP' THEN amount/0.85
--                  WHEN transaction_type = 'pay_out'                      THEN 0
                    WHEN transaction_type = 'pay_out' AND currency = 'EUR' THEN -amount
                    WHEN transaction_type = 'pay_out' AND currency = 'GBP' THEN -amount/0.85               END) AS amount_eur
    FROM       deposit_transactions dt
    INNER JOIN customers c
            ON dt.customer_id = c.customer_id
    GROUP BY country,
             transaction_date
), ranked_countries AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                  PARTITION BY transaction_date
                  ORDER     BY amount_eur DESC ) AS rn
    FROM   total_amounts_per_country
)
SELECT transaction_date, 
       country
FROM ranked_countries
WHERE rn = 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u9hQ4jtaHhC2QmQARFEtyK/0).